# How can I automatically highlight a select box based on a value from xml?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have select boxes that get there values from an XML file. When the program loads, it automatically displays the information form the first value in the XML file. I also need it to highlight that value in the select box.

This is how it looks when it is initially loaded
[image]

Since it is automaticaly loading those images, I want that type selected in the select box ("By Color" -> "Barnwood")
[image]

(The code I have inherited has a ton of files, so I'm only going to show the code I think is relevant. I have very limited knowledge in Flex...)

```
            private function onCatReceived(e:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var cats:Array= new Array();
                loadItems(Globals.compRoot+catDataProvider.lastResult.elements("category")[0].catid);
                for each(var cat:XML in catDataProvider.lastResult.elements("category"))
                {
                    if (cats[cat.parent.toString()])
                    {
                        cats[cat.parent.toString()].addItem(cat);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cats[cat.parent.toString()]= new ArrayCollection();
                        cats[cat.parent.toString()].addItem(cat);
                    }

                }
                for (var ct:String in cats)
                {
                    var cnv:Canvas= new Canvas();
                    var dataSort:SortField= new SortField("name",true);
                    var nameSort:Sort= new Sort();
                    nameSort.fields=[dataSort];
                    var source:ArrayCollection=cats[ct];
                    source.sort=nameSort;
                    source.refresh();
                    cnv.label=ct;
                    cnv.horizontalScrollPolicy="off";
                    cnv.verticalScrollPolicy="off";
                    var lst:List= new List();
                    lst.width=166;
                    lst.height=115;
                    lst.labelField="name";
                    lst.styleName="ControllerList";
                    lst.addEventListener(ListEvent.CHANGE,changeCat);

                    lst.dataProvider=cats[ct];
                    Alert.show("ct: " + ct);
                    cnv.addChild(lst);
                    acc.addChild(cnv);
                }
                //Maybe add it here??
                //mouldingList.items.selectedIndex = 0;
                var cnv:Canvas = acc.getChildAt(0) as Canvas;
                var lst:List = cnv.getChildAt(1) as List;
                Alert.show(lst.toString());
                Alert.show(lst.selectedItem.toString());

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

- I changed the way the Accordion adds the child, so that I could control the index of each child
- I went through each Canvas in the Accordion and set the selectedIndex of the Accordion of the List if it matched "By Color" as the label.

  ```
  private function onCatReceived(e:ResultEvent):void
  {
      var cats:Array= new Array();
      loadItems(Globals.compRoot+catDataProvider.lastResult.elements("category")[0].catid);
      for each(var cat:XML in catDataProvider.lastResult.elements("category"))
      {
          if (cats[cat.parent.toString()])
          {
              cats[cat.parent.toString()].addItem(cat);
          }
          else
          {
              cats[cat.parent.toString()]= new ArrayCollection();
              cats[cat.parent.toString()].addItem(cat);
          }

      }
      for (var ct:String in cats)
      {
          var cnv:Canvas= new Canvas();
          var dataSort:SortField= new SortField("name",true);
          var nameSort:Sort= new Sort();
          nameSort.fields=[dataSort];
          var source:ArrayCollection=cats[ct];
          source.sort=nameSort;
          source.refresh();
          cnv.label=ct;

          cnv.horizontalScrollPolicy="off";
          cnv.verticalScrollPolicy="off";
          var lst:List= new List();
          lst.width=166;
          lst.height=115;
          lst.labelField="name";
          lst.styleName="ControllerList";
          lst.addEventListener(ListEvent.CHANGE,changeCat);

          lst.dataProvider=cats[ct];
          //Alert.show("ct: " + ct);
          cnv.addChild(lst);
          acc.addChild(cnv);

          switch (ct)
          {
              case "By Color":
                  acc.addChildAt(cnv, 0);
                  break;

              case "By Material":
                  acc.addChildAt(cnv, 1);
                  break;

              case "By Style":
                  acc.addChildAt(cnv, 2);
                  break;

              default:
                  acc.addChild(cnv);

          }


          //acc.addChildAt(cnv, 0);
      }



      //Set the selected item to be the 0th item

      for each (var o:Object in acc.getChildren())
      {
          if (o is Canvas)
          {
              var c:Canvas = o as Canvas;
              if ("By Color" == c.label)
              {

                  c.setFocus(); //does this work?
                  c.drawFocus(true); //does this work?
                  acc.selectedIndex = 0; //does this work?
                  for each (var o2:Object in o.getChildren())
                  {
                      if (o2 is List)
                      {
                          var l:List = o2 as List;



                          l.selectedIndex = 0;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  ```